# Magento, Solr returns no items

Tags: magento, solr

I am having issues getting solr to return any products from a search. Layered navigation is working, but search will not return products.

I have browsed through several sites during setup and config and seem to have everything set up correctly. I have also searched the web for a long time trying to find answers to this specific problem. Here are some things I've already tried:

http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/magento-search-displays-your-search-returns-no-results/

http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-searching-by-sku-with-solr-bonus-using-stop-words/

[Magento SOLR doesn't return results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567410/magento-solr-doesnt-return-results)

And I have tried more. Reindexing, clearing cache(s), refreshing attributes, but nothing I have found seems to work. Here are the more specific issues I am facing. Somehow, I dnt seem to be able to search by sku, even in the solr admin. If i look under my scheme browser, I have data in all the fields except the ones related to sku. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is what a sample query looks like:

```
    Mar 26, 2015 11:14:04 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
    INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} hits=0 status=0 QTime=4

    Mar 26, 2015 11:14:04 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
    INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} status=0 QTime=5

    Mar 26, 2015 11:14:05 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
    INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={spellcheck=true&sort=score+desc&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&json.nl=map&spellcheck.collate=true&wt=json&version=1.2&rows=1&fl=id&start=0&q=ge&spellcheck.dictionary=magento_spell_en&spellcheck.count=2&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1} hits=0 status=0 QTime=3

    Mar 26, 2015 11:14:05 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
    INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={facet=on&sort=score+desc&facet.query=category_ids:116&facet.query=category_ids:841&facet.query=category_ids:259&facet.query=category_ids:694&facet.query=category_ids:320&start=0&q=ge&facet.field=attr_nav_multi_features&json.nl=map&qt=magento_en&wt=json&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1&version=1.2&rows=9999} hits=0 status=0 QTime=5
```

Thanks in advance for your help. This has been an issue for the past couple of days.